# Get the connected serial port in arduino via code

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port

I have a simple serial connection with arduino, and I need to know the COM that the arduino is connected via code.

For example, i have another application in Java that connect on COM3 and send/receive commands via serial with the arduino, in Java program I know the port (is COM3), but i need to know the communication port in arduino code.

Answer (score 0):

The communication port of the arduino is always the port you have connected the hardware usb to serial converter to. If you are using a Arduino UNO, it is always Serial Port 1.

There is no way an arduino can know the COM port number, as it is assigned by the operating system of your computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your Java program (PC) to tell your Arduino program which COM port it is connected to. You would let the Java program print a "command" with the  port number on that serial port, and let your arduino program receive that command with for example `Serial.readString()`